# how to route Traffic from specific port through specific NIC / Gateway?

Tags: ip, bind, gateway

I tried a few solutions, like binding and iptables.
But nothing worked for me.
What i want to do is using some applications like Firefox with wlan0 nic for example. and eth0 for everything else.
I know i can make it work with virtualization but thats overkill and not practical cause i wanna do this in Raspberry pi.

Comment: Create a network namespace for "some applications like Firefox", move `wlan0` to this namespace, start Firefox etc. in this namespace.